# can't execute code on ipod touch 4th gen

Tags: xcode, deployment, ipod-touch

I can't execute an app i have developed for iOs 5.
It works fine on my iPhone 4, but not on my iPod Touch 4th Gen.

I added the iPod to the list of devices used for development in the Xcode Organizer.

But when i press the 'Run' button, Xcode compiles successfully (states 'Build succeeded' in the middle of the screen) and suddenly tells me 'Finished running MyApp on m's iPod'

i'm using Xcode 4.2, iOS is 5.01 on iPod and iPhone.

The App can be tested on the iPhone 4 or in the simulator, but not on the iPod. It's doesn't even start, so an immediate crash of the app is not the reason!

Who knows how to cope with this phenomenon?

Comment: did u try to update your provisioning profiles manually? sometimes it gets bugged or something and the issue usually fixed with updating it.

Comment: go to your developer account, in the provisioning section. if u didn't make a provision profile with an appID make one and make sure you select the iPod in the list of devices for that profile, download the file created and add it to your xCode.

Comment: solved the issue without provisioning profile update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue was very easy to solve, but hard to find (for me) as no error report nor any message from Xcode gave a hint:

In the Info.plist file, the section **Required device capabilities** contained *gps* and *magnetometer*.

Both aren't available on the iPod.

After removing those required device capabilites the App worked on the iPod